# search a block of variables for null variables Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a group of UIImageView's which have outlets which are boardImage1, boardImage2 etc up to 9.

How could I run a search programmatically in a loop that finds which are set to NULL and does stuff with them?

Also how would I reference them I can't use boardImage[i] as its not an array

Many thanks

Comment: are you looking for not connected outlets? why would the views ever be nil otherwise

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing multiple outlets, you can use an outlet collection and have multiple board images in a single collection.

Comment: Grab the chance to use IBOutletCollection :) I think it might be the best solution

Comment: Not much more useful than my answer; you cannot have `nil` elements in an outlet collection (it's based on an `NSArray`).

Comment: I don't think this would work at all for the OPs issue. the IBOutletCollection is an array or set and can't contain nil

Comment: Well if you want to loop through outlets and reference individual ones, the best way to go is to use an outlet collection

Comment: That's not what the OP wants though.

Comment: How is it not, his problem was that his outlets were not an array.

Comment: He wants to find the outlets that are `nil` and they cannot be `nil` in an outlet collection, so how does using one help?

Comment: He wants an outlet which has image sets to nil as i guess. you can not create nil outlet.

Comment: If that's the case then an outlet collection is perfect.  However the OP needs to be more precise with his questions.  Getting involved in the discussion wouldn't hurt either.  People who show no interest in their questions are annoying.

Comment: The main point is the scanning for empty null variables in a group; the statement about referencing was just a guess on how I would normally access the variables.